# Deploying Spring Boot App in Wildfly 9.0.2

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly

I want to deploy a simple Spring Boot Rest app into a Wildfly 9.0.2 server.  It seems to deploy but can't access any of the services.

I have been following various instructions such as:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

but still doesn't seem to work for me.

This is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.vodafone.er</groupId>
<artifactId>config-app</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>config-app</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>com.vodafone.er.configapp.ConfigAppApplication</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<!--<build>-->
    <!--<plugins>-->
        <!--<plugin>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
            <!--<configuration>-->
                <!--<jvmArguments>-->
                    <!-- -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005-->
                <!--</jvmArguments>-->
            <!--</configuration>-->
        <!--</plugin>-->
    <!--</plugins>-->
<!--</build>-->
```

And here is my application / controller class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ConfigAppApplication extends     
    SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigAppApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(ConfigAppApplication.class);
        }
    }

    @RestController
    class ConfigController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

I deploy it on the $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments and it tells me it is deployed.

```
15:51:12,008 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "config-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" with deployment "config-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"
```

and I get the marker file:

```
config-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.deployed
```

The jmx console tells me the application is enabled too.
Whenever I try and access the endpoint e.g. when I try and access the root-context I get a 403 forbidden, but when I try and access the rest resource e.g. localhost:8080/config-app/hello I get a 404 error.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is that the entire source of `ConfigAppApplication`? It's missing `@SpringBootApplication` or the equivalent separate annotations.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to deploy a standalone app on an application server.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson - I have edited the question.  Think I removed it by accident so thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @KarlNicholas - The question is not really about whether it makes sense.  This is a test to see if it works in this version of Wildfly before I integrate it into an existing Wildfly with multiple web apps in it.  I can get this to work easily with an embedded Tomcat/Jetty for example but following the example I mentioned I cannot use the rest service.  I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm a little confused why your pom specifically excludes the tomcat dependency and then explicitly includes it again later on. This seems the result of drastic random testing (the commented out build section is further proof of that) rather than being a proper clean pom for us to examine.

Comment: @Gimby I wanted to show some of the things I have tried.  So I tried removing the tomcat dependency (then later added it back), since I am trying to deploy it into Wildfly which comes with undertow provided.  Also I tried both using the spring-boot-maven-plugin and without.  Either way I will remove the tomcat exclusion in the pom to make it less confusing.

Answer (score 4):

Wildfly uses undertow servlet container. Try adding support for that in your application.

Ref: [73.13 Use Undertow instead of Tomcat](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-use-undertow-instead-of-tomcat)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I can give that a go, but Wildfly provides Undertow ... so I would want to use that Undertow server at runtime - not the spring boot dependency.

Comment: Read the docs, I think they said the springboot-undertow simply attaches to the undertow container. I think this may be true in general for springboot servlet container libraries.

Comment: This is really valuable info that I haven't seen elsewhere ^

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
```