# Spring boot app in WildFly 7 - endpoint not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss

As I started to maintain a legacy app that runs inside JBoss 7x (yep), I try to create a prototype with a modern spring boot stack (2.7 because of JDK 8). I am able to deploy the app as war to JBoss, but invoking a rest controller returns 404 error.

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.16</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>demo</name>
<description>demo</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

DemoApplication.java

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
operational-decision-manager-decision-center
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        System.err.println("\n\nCONFIGURE\n\n");
        return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }
```

src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/demo</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

GreetingController.java

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {
    String subject = "World";

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting() {
        return "Hello, " + subject + "!";
    }

    @PostMapping("/subject/{subject}")
    public boolean setSubject(@PathVariable String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
        return true;
    }
}
```

$JBOSS_PATH/modules/system/layers/base/jdk/unsupported/main

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.5" name="jdk.unsupported"></module>
```

The first finding is that the `DemoApplication#configure` is never called. And maybe that's why the app sources are not scanned and the controller is not initialized.

When I access http://localhost:4000/demo/greeting, I will receive: `BWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - /demo/greeting`

When I access URL outside of the context, it responds with HTTP error 404:

```
This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:4000/xyz
HTTP ERROR 404
```

As you can see, the first response is decorated by JBoss, the latter not. I even tried to add an actuator but its endpoint is not reachable either.

Other questions I reviewed:

- [RESTful Endpoints Not Found on Wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76811128/restful-endpoints-not-found-on-wildfly)
- [Deploying Spring Boot App in Wildfly 9.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46039823/deploying-spring-boot-app-in-wildfly-9-0-2)

PS I receive hundreds of warning like this but I assume that they are harmless

```
12:56:39,518 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS015852: Could not index class org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/InterceptorRegistry.class at /C:/dev/Lion/JBoss/bin/content/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-5.3.30.jar: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=12 poolCount = 149
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.processConstantPool(Indexer.java:606) [jandex-1.0.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.3.Final-redhat-2]
```

Comment: Nothing looks wrong here.  This is how you do it.  Check your security settings and your deployment info.  When you deploy, validate (as best you can) that it deploys the war as expected.

Comment: I tried to downgrade spring boot and since 2.4 the configurer was hit. But then I ran into a conflict with jboss activation api version 1.1 and I was unable to resolve it. It looks like JBoss 7.4 is not compatible with spring boot 2.x.

Comment: This guy has similar experience: https://conorprunty.medium.com/issues-with-deploying-a-spring-boot-application-onto-jboss-abfd6392593b

Comment: I'm assuming you mean a version of JBoss EAP 7. Could you be more specific on which version you're targetting?

Comment: It is the 7.4.1 version